# Using a constexpr C-string as compiler error message

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

As the question suggests what I would like to do is

```
template<const char* Err>
struct broken
{
    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr broken(Args&&...)
    {
        //the sizeof... confuses the compiler as to only emit errors when instantiated
        //this does not work, static_assert only accepts string literals
        static_assert(sizeof...(Args) < 0, Err);
    }
};
```

What I hope for is that `broken` emit an compiler error message `Err` whenever instantiated. However, `static_assert` exclusively accepts only a string literal as its second argument. Is there any way to emit a compiler error based on a `constexpr` string?

Comment: While the use case is unclear, the answer to the question as posted is 'no'. There is no way to use anything than string literal as a second argument to `static_assert`.

Comment: *Since message has to be a string literal, it cannot contain dynamic information or even a constant expression that is not a string literal itself. In particular, it cannot contain the name of the template type argument.* [source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)

Comment: I'm not asking for a `static_assert` solution. I'm well aware that it only accepts string literals. I'm asking for a solution for emitting a compiler error based on a `constexpr` string.

Comment: @SergeyA The use case is to emit a readable error amidst a pile of crazy diagnostics from template meta-programming

Comment: What I've seen done in Boost is trigger an error which includes the name of a type, which is actually the error message. You then get things such as `instantiation of undefined template t<ERROR_SOMETHING_IS_BROKEN>` in your build log.

Comment: @Quentin Yah, I know of their existence. But in my opinion is insanely horrible to use. Also, they produce a *ton* of noise, adding to the already crazy compiler message. Comparing to `static_assert`s, which documents what it asserts in code, and produces really nice messages: `error: static assertion failed: error message`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want cannot possibly work in any shape or form, because you can legitimately do

```
extern const char foo[];
template <const char* err> class broken {};
broken<foo> tisbroken;
```

and `foo` need not even be defined in the current TU (or anywhere else for that matter) for this to compile.

An ODR-use of `err` inside `foo` would lead to a linker error when `foo` is undefined, but that would be way too late.

So no, you cannot use a string passed to a template to print compiler messages, *because there's no string*.